# Pyplot, using the slider to graph many different lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use pyplot to create an interactive picture with many (really a lot...) of lines.

All of these lines are stored in a list of lists where the first element of each list is a parameter of a model and the next 5 elements are output I want to graph as a line.

I can plot the lines for a given parameter (first element) but how can I get the slider to function so that I see what happens as I change the parameter?  Right now changing the slider just blanks out the lines and only the axes remain.

I'm guessing that there is something about how I'm drawing the multiple lines each time that makes it difficult for the program to pull the information out for the new plot.  I appreciate the help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
import numpy as np

#the list of lists.
equilibria = np.loadtxt('foo', delimiter = ',')
equilibria = equilibria.tolist()

#a function that extracts the lines based on the first element
def lines_param(z1):
    lines_z1=[]
    for x in equilibria:
        if x[0]==z1:
            lines_z1.append(x[1:6])
    return lines_z1

#the x-axis values on plot, same for every line.
x_m=[-1.0,-0.5,0.0,0.5,1.0]

#setting up the slider
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axz1 = plt.axes([0.125,0.1,0.775,0.03], axisbg = axcolor)
sz1 = Slider(axz1, '$Z_1$',-2.1,2.1, valinit=-1.5)

#the starting lines plotted
z1= -1.5
lines=lines_param(z1)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.axis([-1.0,1.0,0,10])
for y in lines:
    plt.plot(x_m, y, linewidth=.2)

#what happens when the slider updates
def updated(val):
    z1 = sz1.val
    lines=lines_param(z1)
    #clear out the old lines and plot the new ones
    plt.cla()
    for y in lines:
        plt.plot(x_m, y, linewidth=.2)

sz1.on_changed(updated)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you plot all the lines at once? If not, please explain why.

Comment: There are many.  Like 20+ or even more for each parameter and the space of the parameters is large as well.  The goal of being able to look at them interactively is that I can see how the lines change and which ones drop out as the parameters change.

It could be possible to have all of them at once and then color code by parameter but that might look really jumbled, because it's many lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `plt.draw()` inside of your "updated" function like so:

```
def updated(val):
    z1 = sz1.val
    lines=lines_param(z1)
    #clear out the old lines and plot the new ones
    plt.cla()
    for y in lines:
        plt.plot(x_m, y, linewidth=.2)
    plt.draw()
```

I was unable to get your code running on my machine because I am not sure how the data your 'foo' directory is structured.  If you could post the format of your data it would be easier to debug your issue.

Comment: You didn't state where to put it.  If I put it in the function I get an error that plt does not have attribute "canvas".  When I place it in the for loop then nothing is changed from before.

Comment: try calling `plt.draw()` instead of `plt.canvas.draw_idle()`.  I showed your function after adding the line that I suggested in my answer.